# RxJava make retryWhen() fire to onError() method

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have a following class with RxJava implementation for download two resources from API. I do some rx to allow it retry or repeat when it don't meet api/connection requirements. However, I cannot make retryWhen() fire onError() after attempt more than 3 times.

**QUESTION / HELP**

please, review my code and help me solve this issue.

**NOTE**

I'm implement Rx by read these two articles.
[article 1](https://medium.com/@v.danylo/server-polling-and-retrying-failed-operations-with-retrofit-and-rxjava-8bcc7e641a5a#.5itt4nvkl), [article 2](http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/)

**SplashPresenter.class**

```
public class SplashPresenter implements SplashContract.Presenter {

    private static final String TAG = SplashPresenter.class.getName();
    private static final int RETRY_TIMEOUT = 10;
    private static final int STOP_RETRY_TIME = 3;
    private static final int START_RETRY_TIME = 1;


    private SplashContract.View mView;

    @Override
    public void init(SplashContract.View view) {
        this.mView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        GetRemoteReceiverRelationshipSpec relationSpec = new GetRemoteReceiverRelationshipSpec();
        GetRemoteIncompleteReasonSpec reasonSpec = new GetRemoteIncompleteReasonSpec();

        Observable<RepoResult<ArrayList<IncompleteReasonViewModel>>> queryReason =
                Repository.getInstance().query(reasonSpec);

        Repository.getInstance().query(relationSpec)
                .concatMap(result -> queryReason)
                .repeatWhen(complete -> complete
                        .zipWith(Observable.range(START_RETRY_TIME, STOP_RETRY_TIME), (v, i) -> i)
                        .flatMap(repeatCount -> {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Repeat attempt: " + repeatCount);
                            mView.showLoadingDialog();
                            return Observable.timer(RETRY_TIMEOUT,
                                    TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                        }))
                .takeUntil(RepoResult::isSuccess)
                .retryWhen(error -> error
                        .zipWith(Observable.range(START_RETRY_TIME, STOP_RETRY_TIME), (v, i) -> i)
                        .flatMap(retryCount -> {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Retry attempt: " + retryCount);
                            mView.showLoadingDialog();
                            if (mView.getCommunicator() != null) {
                                mView.getCommunicator().onConnectionFail(retryCount);
                            }
                            return Observable.timer(RETRY_TIMEOUT,
                                    TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                        }))
                .filter(RepoResult::isSuccess)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        result -> Log.i(TAG, "onNext()"),
                        err -> {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onError()");
                            if (mView.getCommunicator() != null) {
                                mView.dismissLoadingDialog();
                                mView.getCommunicator().onSplashScreeDismissError();
                            }
                        },
                        () -> {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onComplete()");
                            if (mView.getCommunicator() != null) {
                                mView.dismissLoadingDialog();
                                mView.getCommunicator().onSplashScreenSuccessDismiss();
                            }
                        }
                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I wrote similar code before, I had manually threw `Observable.error()` in `flatMap`

```
.flatMap(retryCount -> {
    if (retryCount >= STOP_RETRY_TIME) {
        return Observable.error(someException);
    }
    return Observable.timer(RETRY_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 }))
```

Comment: @JongzPuangput hi, what happened after that.

Comment: nice! im happy to here that.

Answer (score 2):

To retain the throwable after retrying (instead of emitting a custom one), return an Observable with the appropriate error from the zipWith operator when retryCount is over the specified limit.

```
.retryWhen(error -> {
                Observable<Integer> range = Observable.range(START_RETRY_TIME, STOP_RETRY_TIME);
                Observable<Observable<Long>> zipWith = error.zipWith(range, (e, i) ->
                        i < STOP_RETRY_TIME ?
                                Observable.timer(i, TimeUnit.SECONDS) :
                                Observable.error(e));
                return Observable.merge(zipWith);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the retry counter and error into a `Pair` object if you've reached the retry limit get the exception from pair object and raise it.

```java
source.retryWhen(errors -> errors
                        .zipWith(Observable.range(1, REQUEST_RETRY), Pair::new)
                        .flatMap(errPair -> {
                            int retryTime = errPair.second;
                            if (retryTime < REQUEST_RETRY) {
                                return Observable.timer(retryTime * RETRY_DELAY, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                            } else {
                                return Observable.error(errPair.first);
                            }
                        })
                        .doOnError(this::handleError));
```